# Using value in an input tag with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular front-end.

I'd like to use a component that was created by the team I'm working with, which is used to create an input text in a form.

The .html of this component (let's call it input-text) looks like this :

```html
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
   ....
      <ng-container>
        <input
          ....
          [id]="controlName"
          type="text"
          [formControlName]="controlName"
          [placeholder]="placeholder"
          [value]="value"
      ....
        />
      </ng-container>
   ....
</div>
```

And in his .ts this:

```js
@Input() value = '';
```

And I use it as follows:

```html
 <input-text 
   [formGroup]="formGroup"
   [label]="Name"
   controlName="name">
  </input-text>
```

I've noticed that when the page loads, the existing value of the `name` formControl is not displayed in my page's input. After searching, I found that this component was used by adding `[value]="formGroup.get('name')?.value"` to specify a value to be displayed on loading.

I ask myself the following questions:

- Is it useful to use this `[value]` parameter in the `<input>` tag of
  the component's html? Doesn't Angular allow you to link the
  formControl directly and display its value?
- Another question, I've used this `input-text` component all over the
  place, without ever specifying a value (I hadn't looked at how it was
  used before and I thought the formControl was enough) and I notice
  that in some cases it still displays the value of the formControl and
  in others not.How does this happen? The default value of `value` is an
  empty string, but in some cases it displays the value of the
  formControl. Shouldn't the input always be empty when I don't pass a
  [value]? I can't work out why.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions, since they're referring to some component, about which we know nothing. We don't know what it's supposed to do, how it's supposed to work or the code behind it, i.e. how it actually works. You've pasted arbitrary bits of code and ask arbitrary questions. The only thing I can answer to is - yes, Angular allows binding components to FormControls. Read more about [ControlValueAccessor](ControlValueAccessor). Other than that - create and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try next one** (when new input value comes, you update form control value):

```
// .ts
...    
@Input('value') set _value(name: string) {
  this.formGroup.patchValue({name});  
}
...

// .html
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">  
  <input
    type="text"
    [formControlName]="name"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"  
  />
</div>
```